# Pass variables between different scripts python

Tags: python, flask

I made a script python app.py and I managed to store data from a javascript form, thanks to a flask app :

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db.init_app(app)

@app.route('/getFormData', methods=['POST'])
def get_javascript_data():
    params = request.form.to_dict()
    sunElevation = params['sunElevation']
    cloudCoverage = params['cloudCoverage']
    thresholdNDVI = params['thresholdNDVI']
    limitScene = params['limitScene']
    city = params['city']
    data_search = passData(sunElevation, cloudCoverage, thresholdNDVI, limitScene, city)
    return jsonify(data_search.data_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Here is the definition of the class passData, in models.py :

```
class passData:
    def __init__(self, sunElevation, cloudCoverage, thresholdNDVI, limitScene, city):
        self.sunElevation = sunElevation
        self.cloudCoverage = cloudCoverage
        self.thresholdNDVI = thresholdNDVI
        self.limitScene = limitScene
        self.city = city
        self.data_dict = [{'sunElevation':self.sunElevation,'cloudCoverage':self.cloudCoverage, 'thresholdNDVI':self.thresholdNDVI, 'limit':self.limitScene, 'city':self.city}]
```

I need to use those different parameters (sunElevation...) in an other script, in a other folder, to execute a search of imagery and then run the script associated. My problem is that I don't know how to pass those data, because  they seem to only exist in the fonction defined in the get_javascript_data().

If someone has an idea that could help me !

Comment: why did you define passData as a class while it seems that you need to have it as a function that actually does something with its arguments? Rigth now you're just creating an instance of passData and do nothing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to import the other script, call the function and pass the parameters:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db.init_app(app)

from path.to.your.file import your_function


@app.route('/getFormData', methods=['POST'])
def get_javascript_data():
    params = request.form.to_dict()
    sunElevation = params['sunElevation']
    cloudCoverage = params['cloudCoverage']
    thresholdNDVI = params['thresholdNDVI']
    limitScene = params['limitScene']
    city = params['city']
    data_search = passData(sunElevation, cloudCoverage, thresholdNDVI, limitScene, city)

    # call the function and pass the parameters
    your_function(sunElevation, cloudCoverage) #...

    return jsonify(data_search.data_dict)
```

Comment: I also did it exactly that way when I made a flask app, but did wonder at the time if it was the one and only correct way, although it worked.

Comment: It really depends on what this other function does. You can also create another function callable through ajax, or a method inside your class   `passData`, but if it is a simple different script you can do like that.

Comment: Thanks ! But I have a problem to import the function, I'm not sure of the syntax of my path to the file, could you give me an example ? I put from ../../eosLandviewer/main_naturalite import search

Comment: You can't use "../" when importing.
what is the structure of your project?
Check this:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages/

Comment: In fact this is not a simple script, and inside I'm calling other functions. Someone told me the best way was to use a class and implement a method, but as I'm new to python, I don't see how to instance the method inside my class

Comment: In this case, I recommend you to take some time and check the flask tutorial, it's very simple and they show from zero how to create the correct structure. 
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/

Comment: I left another answer below, try it to import

Comment: ajax does not sound like Python, not sure if it is something to be scared of, thanks will look into it next time I need Flask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I managed to import my script as a function as you said

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code in your file, then import the script

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..')))

from eosLandviewer.main_naturalite import search
```